# Get count of repeat visits

Tags: sql

I have a very simple question that's doing my head in, so I'm turning to stackoverflow for it to be cleared.

I have some category ids on a website, and user_ids. A user_id can visit a category several time, as is shown in the example below.

I want my query to return the number of repeat visitors per category (=visited more than once): e.g. for category 113 it's 2 repeat visitors (user_ids 6 and 5 visited/occur more than once) over a total of 7 total visitors. The idea is to calculate a repeat visit rate (here would be 2/7).

Somehow, my mind is stumped about this. Would appreciate any help, thanks :)

| category_id | user_id |
| --- | --- |
| 113 | 6 |
| 113 | 6 |
| 113 | 5 |
| 113 | 5 |
| 113 | 1 |
| 113 | 7 |
| 113 | 6 |
| 120 | 11 |
| 120 | 11 |
| 120 | 9 |

Many thanks!

Comment: Thanks for showing the example data. Please could you also show the desired results?  Also, please specify which database you're using. MySQL 5.x, MySQL 8, Oracle 18c, SQL Server 2019, etc, etc?

Comment: It would also be useful to update your example to include at least one case of someone visiting three times, and show how that would impact the desired results.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use two levels of aggregation:

```
select category_id,
       sum(case when cnt > 1 then 1 else 0 end) as num_repeat_users
from (select category_id, user_id, count(*) as cnt
      from t
      group by category_id, user_id
     ) cu
group by category_id;
```

Comment: Thank you very much, this was exactly what I wanted to do.